# Unable to get jQuery variable to bring over data into <div> id

Tags: jquery, html, attr

I am reading an `XML` file through a jQuery and want to transfer the value (var_address) to an attribute - "data-address" within a. However, I am unable to do that. I think there is a problem in my jQuery statement, since "var_address" is not picking up any value. Can someone help? Here's what I have:

Thanks a ton in advance.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#paneldetails").append("<ul></ul>");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/datafile.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find('Table1').each(function () {
                var BuildingNumber = $(this).find('BuildingNumber').text();
                var StreetName = $(this).find('StreetName').text();
                var StreetType = $(this).find('StreetType').text();                    
                var City = $(this).find('City').text();
                var State = $(this).find('State').text();
                var ZipCode = $(this).find('ZipCode').text()
                $('div#var_address').attr('data-address', BuildingNumber + '+' + StreetName + '+' + StreetType + '+' + ',' + '+' + City + '+' + ',' + State + '+' + ' ' + ZipCode);  // transfer var0023 to HTML file
                return false;
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error found in the data associated with this record");
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="client" id="var_address" data-address="theaddress" ></div>
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DocumentElement>
<Table1> 
    <Business_x0020_Category>BusinessEssentials</Business_x0020_Category>
    <PanelID>0001</PanelID>
    <Business_x0020_ID>1001</Business_x0020_ID>
    <BusinessName>Acme Tech</BusinessName>
    <BuildingNumber>2173</BuildingNumber>
    <StreetName>Salk</StreetName>
    <StreetType>Ave</StreetType>
    <Suite-Unit_x0020_Number>Suite 600</Suite-Unit_x0020_Number>
    <City>Carlsbad</City>
    <State>CA</State>
    <ZipCode>92008</ZipCode>
    <Telephone>XXX-XXX-XXXX</Telephone>
    <Email>XXXXX@XXXXXX.XXX</Email>
</Table>
```

Comment: Is `Table1` is your `XML element`?

Comment: can you share the xml

Comment: Share ajax response please which your pass through xml

Comment: @RohanKumar Here's the xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DocumentElement>
<Table1>
<Business_x0020_Category>BusinessEssentials</Business_x0020_Category>
<PanelID>0001</PanelID>
<Business_x0020_ID>1001</Business_x0020_ID>
<BusinessName>Acme Tech</BusinessName>
<BuildingNumber>2173</BuildingNumber>
<StreetName>Salk</StreetName>
<StreetType>Ave</StreetType>
<Suite-Unit_x0020_Number>Suite 600</Suite-Unit_x0020_Number>
<City>Carlsbad</City>
<State>CA</State>
<ZipCode>92008</ZipCode>
<Telephone>XXX-XXX-XXXX</Telephone>
<Email>XXXXX@XXXXXX.XXX</Email>
</Table>

Comment: @ArunPJohny AJAX response is success, I am getting other elements come into the JQuery and into the HTML in other <span> elements just fine. Its just that <div class id ...> where data is not coming through

Comment: I believe I am just using wrong syntax or addressing the $('..') incorrectly in the JQuery file. That class - "client" requires that attribute "data-address"in order to operate. So in the JQuery, should I be using some reference to the class within the div in that $('..').attr('data-address' + ..)? How would that change the <div ..> statement in the HTML? Thanks again to ponder over this brain-teaser !

Answer (score 0):

Your `$.each()` is not closed properly and in your `xml` `Table1` is not closed try it like,

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DocumentElement>
<Table1> 
    ...
</Table1><!-- Table1 not Table -->
```

**SCRIPT**

In your `success callback`

```
$(xml).find('Table1').each(function () {
    ......
    return false;
});<-- you missed closing )
```